# ConstraintLayout's Group visibility does not change the visibility of its referenced Views

Tags: android, kotlin

I am launching the Google Play Billing Library's `BillingFlow` per `Button` click and show a loading screen until the user has finished, canceled or an error occurs.

It is working fine for when the user finished or his card has been declined. However, when the user cancels using the back button, the loading screens visibility is changed correctly and it does not do anything in the UI!

Following method is called after the user cancels:

```kotlin
    private fun showContent() {

        Timber.d("showContent: called")

        // Hide the loading screen
        binding.loading.visibility = View.GONE

        // Show the content
        binding.content.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        Timber.d("loading visibility = ${binding.loading.visibility}") // Prints 8 for View.GONE
        Timber.d("content visibility = ${binding.content.visibility}") // Prints 0 for View.VISIBLE

    }
```

As you can see, it prints that the `Group` visibilities are set correctly.

I am using the `Group`s like following:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/loading"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/animated_loading_circle_red_black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/view_pager_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tab_layout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:tabMode="auto"
            />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="progress_bar"
            />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_pager_2,tab_layout"
            />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

I am using the same process to show and hide a loading screen in different `Fragment`s and there it is working fine.

What could be the source of problem here? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue.

I was using `ConstraintLayout` version `1.1.3`. After changing to the [latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.constraintlayout/constraintlayout) `ConstraintLayout` version, the error was gone.